# Laravel Slack on-demand notification; where to set the webhook?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, slack, laravel-5.8

As per the Laravel docs I can do an on-demand notification in a controller like this:

```
use Notification;
use App\Notifications\TradeSuccessful;

$trada_data = array( 'title' => 'test', 'amount' => 123.45 )

Notification::route('slack', '#test')->notify(new TradeSuccessful($trade_data));
```

And in `TradeSuccessful` (example code):

```
public function toSlack($notifiable)
    {
        return (new SlackMessage)
            ->success()
            ->content('One of your invoices has been paid!')
            ->attachment(function ($attachment) use ($trade_data) {
                $attachment->title('Invoice 1322')
                    ->fields([
                    'Title' => $trade_data['title],
                    'Amount' => $trade_data['amount]
                ]);
            });
    }
```

Main question:
when I use Notifications like this (on demand), where do I set the Slack webhook? Because in the documentation they use:

```
public function routeNotificationForSlack($notification)
    {
        return 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/...';
    }
```

But that function is defined on a Model, and when using on demand notifications nothing is defined on a Model.

Comment: In your notification class, how are you able to `use($trade_data)` ? I don't see it declared anywhere. When I try this, my data I pass in doesn't appear in the `$notifiable` variable either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#on-demand-notifications):

> ### On-Demand Notifications
>
> Sometimes you may need to send a notification to someone who is not
> stored as a "user" of your application. Using the
> `Notification::route` method, you may specify ad-hoc notification
> routing information before sending the notification:
>
> ```
> Notification::route('mail', 'taylor@example.com')
>             ->route('vonage', '5555555555')
>             ->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));
> ```

In the case of Slack, the route you specify needs to be the webhook:

```
use Notification;
use App\Notifications\TradeSuccessful;

$tradeData = [
    'title' => 'test',
    'amount' => 123.45,
];

$slackWebhook = 'my-slack-webhook-url'; // <---

Notification::route('slack', $slackWebhook)->notify(new TradeSuccessful($tradeData));
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Of course, you should store is as a config key, but you get the idea.